# Not able to access object property with dashes

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i'm confused about accessing a property from a javascript object.

In this scenario, i'm working with Node.js and Mongoose from find() method

My object:

```
{ 
_id: 52f541c7d2750f2d2cbf6d4a,
descriptions: { 
    'en-us': 'Lorem ipsum',
    'pt-br': 'Os acessórios já não são mais meros coadjuvantes na harmonia de uma    combinação, mas sim a sua assinatura de estilo, dando um caprichoso arremate ao que você escolheu ser pro dia de hoje.' 
},
id: '1',
ids: { 'en-us': 'accessories', 'pt-br': 'acessorios' },
name: 'accessories',
names: { 'en-us': 'Accessories', 'pt-br': 'Acessórios' },
images: { 
    header: '/images/categories/86e3451ca755d31234e5fcad4af055f1',
    unset: [] 
},
position: { x: 650, y: 735 },
active: true 
}
```

Here's the thing:
I'm able to access any property except **object.names**, **object.descriptions** and **object.ids**, it returns 'undefined'.

But when i access the properties with Object.get('property'), i got the expected return.

```
Object.ids = undefined

Object['ids'] = undefined

Object.get('ids') = { 'en-us': 'accessories', 'pt-br': 'acessorios' }
```

Am i missing something here ? Maybe the issue occurs with special chars (In this case, dashes..?)

Hope you guys can help me. Best regards!

Comment: After putting the `_id` value in quotes (`_id: '52f541c7d2750f2d2cbf6d4a'`), it works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/gvXLN/.

Comment: Thanks for the response! This way works, but the     _id property is returned from mongodb, so i think i cant change it...

Comment: Are those fields that are giving you problems defined in your Mongoose schema?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is the way of accessing it.
Only with Object.get('param') i can do this... Better than nothing, while i can't find the real problem/solutions